# How to remove(hide) index from array in PHP. Using http_build_query

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

How to pass an array as a url parameter ? I'm using `http_build_query()`, `array_shift()` and `urldecode()`.

**I have this array:**

```
$array = array(
    'phone' => array('ios', 'android', 'windows')
);
```

When i use `http_build_query` and `urldecode` will return:

```
phone[0]=ios&phone[1]=android&phone[2]=windows
```

When i use `array_shift` will return:

```
0=ios&1=android&2=windows
```

**I want to this:**

```
test.php?phone=ios&phone=android&phone=windows
```

Please help me. How to remove(hide) index from array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryString = "?phone=" . create_query_string(array('ios','windows','android'));
$array = create_array_from_query_string(substr($queryString, 7));

function create_query_string($array) {

    return implode('&phone=', $array);
}

function create_array_from_query_string($queryString) {

    return explode('&phone=', $queryString);
}
```

I suggest using above approach. But you must be familiar with your query string.