# Use array without indexes while using http_build_query

Tags: php, query-string

As recommended [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073329/parameter-gets-lost-when-using-curl) I changed my script to use `http_build_query` to create a well-formed querystring. This works fine except for a small part.

The interface awaits images, there can be several of them, with the same parameter name for all of them, like this:

`&images=$a&images=$b&images=$c`

When using `http_build_query` and passing an array the querystring in the end looks like this:

`&images[0]=$a&images[1]=$b&images[2]=$c`

This will fail with the interface and so I need to get rid of the indexes at all. I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344203/how-to-removehide-index-from-array-in-php-using-http-build-query) but I´d like to stick to `http_build_query`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is with your "interface". It's a valid query string. Except for the fact that square brackets should be encoded to "%5B" for "[" and "%5D" for "]".

Comment: Have you seen if the query parses back to 3 images if you name them all the same key without arraying them?

Comment: @Wazelin It's not a "problem with the interface" either, it's a mismatch of expectations. Yes, `[...]` is *valid*, but if that's not the *expected* way multiple values are defined, that doesn't help.

Comment: But it is the correct one.

Comment: @Rasclatt PHP won't parse them back to an array, no. Other languages/programs do.

Comment: @Wazelin Please point to some official document specifying ***URL syntax*** that says `[...]` is "the correct one".

Comment: @deceze that's good to know! I did not know that.

Comment: Anyway you can strip the indexes down like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170306/http-build-query-with-same-name-parameters).

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me!